# Constants in Java for last hour, minute and second of the day

Tags: java, android

Are there convenient constants in Android or Java for the last hour, minute or second of the day?

I found myself declaring the constants

```
private static final int LAST_HOUR_OF_DAY = 23;
private static final int LAST_MINUTE = 59;
private static final int LAST_SECOND = 59;
```

and wondered if I could already get these somewhere.

Comment: For what purpose do you need those constants?

Comment: Given a Date, I wanted to get the timestamp of the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for this:

```
Date date = //the date you want to work wit
Date endOfDay = new DateTime(date).withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1).toDate();
```

However note that there is a gap of 1s between the resulting Date and the actual end of the day. I would suggest working with the start of the next day and using [before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-).

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely choose to use Joda-Time for future projects as it obviously gives a lot more functionality than the standard Date stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Joda-Time has what you are looking for

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: This is a link only answer.

Comment: Could be be more specific?